# AD for a small office

Tags: active-directory, samba

For a small office with 5 to 8 PCs I want to setup a central windows login like with a windows domain/AD.

There is a NAS for shared folders in place to store data.
I want to grant permissions on the NAS per user based on two groups – so a very simple setup.

What would be the easiest / simple way to setup?

Windows Server? A linux server with SMB? Azure AD DS? Or anything else?

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

If your NAS supports it, Azure AD (not Azure AD DS).

If your NAS dont support it, go all the way with Office365 and store files in the cloud with local sync and use softlinks.